# Strange android network behaviour

Tags: android, ios, networking

I have a simple android app to read a page via HTTP.
It works on first ISP without error.
But when I move to another ISP and run same app on same mobile device, I get **UnknownHostException** or **connection refused** error. Actually I can't even open page via browser on second ISP, seems HTTP Server rejects android ( or java) on some ISPs!
I am accessing HTTP Server via direct valid IP ( so no DNS problem) and my iPhone can open same server on second ISP!

I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

added to correct place in manifest.

The HTTP server is IIS on Windows 2012.

Comment: Maybe set a useragent in the headers?

Comment: can you show your code while connecting? volley?

Comment: @DaanOlislagers No user agent set, but how can I set, maybe I can resolve problem by removing user agent at all!

Comment: Depends on how you create your http request. If you are using a HttpURLConnection you can use `connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","MyAppName/1.0");`

Comment: Show some code, please.